# results shown twice Jquery scroll-to-load-content function, Php & mySql

Tags: php, jquery

I have a scroll-to-load-content function, where

```
 //s > selector which define the number of Sql results given by results.php?selector=s

   jQuery.fn.ShowResults = function(t,s){

    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var track_load=0;
    var total_groups=t;

 $("#results").load("results.php?selector="+s, {'group_no':track_load},  
 function() { track_load++; });

 $(window).scroll(function() { 
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
        {
  if(track_load <= (total_groups-1) && loading==false)
    /*I think that in this line is the clue*/
         {
             loading = true;

              $.post("results.php?selector="+s, {'group_no':track_load}, function() { 

             $('#results').append(data); 
             track_load++; 
             loading = false; 
            });
          }
      }
                         }                      
  }

 $("#results").ShowResults(8,1);

 $("#show1").on("click", function(e){  $("#results").ShowResults(8,1);});
 $("#show2").on("click", function(e){  $("#results").ShowResults(6,2);});
 $("#show3").on("click", function(e){  $("#results").ShowResults(4,3);});
```

I have by default `selector=1`;

```
 <a id=show1>Show 1</a>
 <a id=show2>Show 2</a>
 <a id=show3>Show 3</a>

 <ul id=results></ul>
```

PHP `results.php?selector=1` would be

```
if($_POST)
{

$data_per_group=10; //each group return 10 records as maximun
$group_number = $_POST["group_no"];

$position = ($group_number * $data_per_group);

 $s=$_GET['selector'];
 if($s==1){$results=mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE condition1 LIMIT $position, $data_per_group");}
 if($s==2){$results=mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE condition2 LIMIT $position, $data_per_group");}
 if($s==3){$results=mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE condition3 LIMIT $position, $data_per_group");}


 while($res=mysql_fetch_array($results)){

 $data=$res['names'];
 echo "<li>$data</li>";
} 

 }
```

the problem is that sometimes, it looks like the function is called twice, and shows the same results repeated like this

```
  <ul id=results>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCC</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCC</li>
  </ul>
```

I have tried to use `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` with no solution

The question is how do I stop this function behaviour? It looks like that anytime I click the anchors, I call twice the same function and conflicts with the set by default. I was adviced to us `mysql_fetch_row()` but the problem is still on. update. After testing many times, I realize That it shows twice becouse of the scroll. I need to improve this lines `if(track_load <= (total_groups-1) && loading==false)` or maybe anytime I click an anchor the function takes the number of groups `total_groups` from the default release.

Comment: What you see when you enter directly to `results.php?selector=1`?

Comment: I edited the question in order to let you know that

Comment: What is the exact query? The problem is in that, because jQuery's `load` overrides the existing content, so even if it would be executed twice, it'll show the result of the last "execution". (sorry for my bad English `:(`)

Comment: Its just a basic query, well in this question I tried to sumarize the function, but the real one is like this https://jsfiddle.net/mz40o542/1/

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: How do you use the `group_no` in the query?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mz40o542/2/ please check this update.

Comment: Is your query return the same result in phpmyadmin?
If not then check your parameters passing to jquery fn.

Comment: In phpmyadmin,everything goes well. the Jquery scroll function, sometimes shows twice the same content. this is the issue i would like to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the issue, thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

the problem it was that anytime I click an anchor `a`, for some reason, the page still keept the prior value of `total_groups`.

```
jQuery.fn.ShowResults = function(t,s){

var total_groups=t;

   setInterval( function(){alert(total_groups);},2000)

  /*more coding*/
 }
```

By default it was set `selector=1` `$("#results").ShowResults(8,1);` .So when I clicked on `a id=show2` `$("#results").ShowResults(6,2);`, it can be seen alerts ,`setInterval()`, showing different `total_groups` values, 8 & 6. And if I press `a id=show3` `$("#results").ShowResults(4,2);`, the alert in one moment will display  8,6 & 4. Why this happens I still dont know.

so I decided to add `$ajax({});` in order to obtain `total_groups` from another page `total_groups.php?s=selector` which returns the total_groups value only.

```
jQuery.fn.ShowResults = function(s){

$ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "total_groups.php?s="+selector,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data) {

                var total_groups=data; //I obtain total_groups by ajax now.

                              $("#results").load();

                                    $(window).scroll(function() { 

                                                   /*append data code*/

                                                             }//end load scroll
                          }//end success
      });//end ajax
  }//end function
```

So by using Ajax, the problem is finally solve.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `track_load` from `0` to `1`.

The `.load()` request already gets the first 'track', yet the first `$.post` request requests track_load `0` again.

Comment: I think this is not the answer, I improved the question, please check it out

Comment: Its not hard, the thing is I am focused in the `Jquery` mainly. The `selector` value determines which of the three statements have to be used.

Comment: I added the `sql` arrangement, thanks you for helping.

Comment: You tried my answer? Because in the second Ajax request the position is still 0.

Comment: I did, the function works ok, but sometimes shows the results twice...this is  the real problem